# After collspan and rowspan cells are floating outside the table

Tags: javascript, html-table

[https://drive.google.com/drive/my-drive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0I9b.png)this is the simple calender that can be used to book the appointment. i tried many solution like loops and conditional statement but i cant get the proper output 
the main issue is that when cal span and row span is happening at the time cells are floating outside the table   the total number of cells are floating is equql to the   ((enddate - startdate) * (endtime - starttime) + (enddate - startdate) + (endtime - starttime))  this formula .

```js
var startdate= "";
        var enddate= "";
        var delcell = ((enddate - startdate) * (endtime - starttime) + (enddate - startdate) + (endtime - starttime)/2 );
        var starttime= "";
        var endtime= "";

        var label = "";
        function datasubmit(){
            document.getElementById('s1');
            startdate = document.getElementById('startd').value;
            enddate = document.getElementById('endd').value;
            starttime = document.getElementById('startt').value;
            endtime = document.getElementById('endt').value;
            label = document.getElementById('label').value;
            document.getElementById('table').innerHTML = ''
            calender()
    }



        function calender(){
            for (var j = 0; j <= 24; j++) {

            let row = table.insertRow(j);

            for (var i = 1; i <= 30; i++) {
                if(j==0){
                    var newcell = row.insertCell(-1);
                    newcell.innerHTML = i + 'Jan';

                }else{
                    var newcell = row.insertCell(-1);
                    newcell.innerHTML = '';

                    if(j==starttime && i==startdate ){
                        newcell.setAttribute('rowspan', (endtime-starttime)+1);
                        newcell.setAttribute('colspan', (enddate-startdate)+1);

                        newcell.innerHTML =label;
                    }

                }
            }

            var newcell = row.insertCell(0);
            newcell.innerHTML = j + 'HR';
        }
        }
        calender()
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>calender in js</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        table td{
            border: 1px solid grey;
            padding: 4px;

        }

    </style>

</head>
<body> 
    <form autocomplete="off" id="s1">
        start date <input type="text" name="startd" id="startd">
        end date <input type="text" name="endd" id="endd"><br><br>
        start time <input type="text" name="startt" id="startt">
        end time <input type="text" name="endt" id="endt"><br><br>
        inter name <input type="text" name="label" id="label">
        <button type="button" name="submit" id="submit" onclick="datasubmit();">Submit</button><br><br>

    </form>
    <table id="table" style="border:2px solid black">

    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
```

as i calculated the the floating cells are ((enddate  - startdate) * (endtime - starttime) +   (enddate  - startdate) + (endtime - starttime))

Comment: Could you possibly add a screenshot of the behavior you're seeing?

Comment: Do you see the rendering issue on load or only when you add a new entry?

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow! I created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8e0y3q2o/) for your problem, so everyone can see what you are seeing. Is the problem present in the fiddle? Can you exactly describe, what the difference to your desired result is?

Comment: yes sir !  i recently added link in the comment